# If $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are cyclic then $G''=G'''$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that, if $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are both cyclic then $G''=G'''$.

I was expecting this proof would be similar to the proof of

> $$G/Z(G)~~~~ \text{is cyclic} \Rightarrow G~~~ \text{is abelian}$$

I tried in that way but i could reach nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: @Babak S : Thanks for Your Edit. :) COuld you please give some hint regarding this problem.

Comment: Is $G'$ the commutator subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, Yes. $G'$ is commutator subgroup of $G$. I was expecting that it is standard Notation.So, did not mention it

Comment: Well, I've seen $K(G)$, $[G,G]$ and $G'$ for the commutator subgroup. Possibly some I've forgotten.

Comment: This is trickier than I expected. Notice that it does not work with $G/G'$ and $G'/G''$, as with $G=S_4$ we get $G'=A_4$ and $G''=V_4$, so $G/G'\cong C_2$, $G'/G''\cong C_3$ but $G/G''\cong S_3$. It has to be used in the proof that the top group is already a commutator subgroup of something.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes Yes. I have no hope. I tried to confirm myself by some example but it is getting more complicated :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the third isomorphism theorem, we may as well assume that $G''' = 1$.
So we are given that $G'/G''$ and $G''/G''' = G''$ are cyclic, and we want to show that $G'' = 1$, or rather that $G'$ is abelian.

We will use the fact that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, the quotient $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.

Since $G''$ is normal, we have $G = N_G(G'')$.
Then by the fact we just mentioned, $G/C_G(G'')$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$.
But $G''$ is cyclic, so $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$ is an abelian group.
Thus $G/C_G(G'')$ is abelian, and so $G' \subset C_G(G'')$. 
But this means that $G'' \subset Z(G')$.

From here the proof follows from the fact

> $$ N \subset Z(G), ~ G/N ~~ \text{cyclic} \Rightarrow G~~ \text{is abelian} ,$$

the proof of which is basically the same as the proof of the fact about $G/Z(G)$ you mentioned.

Comment: Can the third isomorphism theorem be applied? Is $G'''$ necessarily normal in $G'$?

Comment: All terms in the derived series are characteristic and hence normal in $G$.

Comment: Good to know, @DerekHolt.

Comment: May I know why we can just assume $G'''=1$?

Answer (score -1):

Exercise~4.4.10 verifies action by conjugation of $G/G^{\prime\prime}$ on the cyclic group $G^{\prime\prime}$. Observe that the kernel of the associated homomorphism into the abelian group $\text{Aut}\left(G^{\prime\prime}\right)$ (see Proposition~4.4.16) is $Z\left(G\right)/G^{\prime\prime}$ and $\left(G/G^{\prime\prime}\right)/\left(Z\left(G\right)/G^{\prime\prime}\right)\cong G/Z\left(G\right)$ is isomorphic to an abelian subgroup of $\text{Aut}\left(G^{\prime\prime}\right)$. Then $G^{\prime}/Z\left(G\right)\leq\left(G/Z\left(G\right)\right)^{\prime}=Z\left(G\right)$ so the complete preimage of $G^{\prime}/Z\left(G\right)$ is $G^{\prime}=Z\left(G\right)$. It follows that $G^{\prime\prime}=1=G^{\prime\prime\prime}$.

Consider a group $K$ so $K^{\prime}/K^{\prime\prime}$ and $K^{\prime\prime}/K^{\prime\prime\prime}$ are cyclic, and $K^{\prime\prime\prime}$ is non-trivial. Then $G=K/K^{\prime\prime\prime}$ satisfies the hypotheses $G^{\prime}/G^{\prime\prime}$ and $G^{\prime\prime}$ are cyclic, and $G^{\prime\prime\prime}=1$. That is, $1=G^{\prime\prime}=K^{\prime\prime}/K^{\prime\prime\prime}$ so $K^{\prime\prime}=K^{\prime\prime\prime}$. Thus the result.

References to Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, 3rd Ed.