# Why $G'' \triangleleft G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derived-subgroup

Here is the question I want to solve:

Show that if $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are both cyclic then $G'' = G'''$.  [you may assume $G''' = 1$. Then $G/G''$ acts by conjugation on the cyclic group $G''$.

Here is the solution I found here [If $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are cyclic then $G''=G'''$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478125/if-g-g-and-g-g-are-cyclic-then-g-g/478175#478175) :

By the third isomorphism theorem, we may as well assume that $G''' = 1$.
So we are given that $G'/G''$ and $G''/G''' = G''$ are cyclic, and we want to show that $G'' = 1$, or rather that $G'$ is abelian.

We will use the fact that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, the quotient $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.

Since $G''$ is normal, we have $G = N_G(G'')$.
Then by the fact we just mentioned, $G/C_G(G'')$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$.
But $G''$ is cyclic, so $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$ is an abelian group.
Thus $G/C_G(G'')$ is abelian, and so $G' \subset C_G(G'')$.
But this means that $G'' \subset Z(G')$.

From here the proof follows from the fact

> $$ N \subset Z(G), ~ G/N ~~ \text{cyclic} \Rightarrow G~~ \text{is abelian} ,$$

the proof of which is basically the same as the proof of the fact about $G/Z(G)$ you mentioned.

**My question is:**

Is there a rigor proof for the idea that  $G'' \triangleright G$, in our case, that the author used in the answer? I do not know why this is correct, my professor even emphasized that $G^{(n)} \triangleleft G^{(n - 1)} \forall n$ but not necessarily $G^{(n)} \triangleleft G  
 \forall n.$

Comment: Huh?  Why is $G$ a normal subgroup of $G''$?

Comment: Should your `\triangleright` in the subject line be `\triangleleft`?

Comment: No, I am saying the inverse @user10354138

Comment: @Brian $G\triangleright H$ means $H$ is a (proper) normal subgroup of $G$.  You want $G\lhd H$ (`G \lhd H`) if you mean $G$ is a (proper) normal subgroup of $H$.

Comment: The commutator subgroup of a group $K$ is not merely normal in $K$, it is *fully invariant* in $K$. In particular, it is characteristic. If $H$ is characteristic in $K$ and $K$ is normal in $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$. All of these are pretty standard facts, and I would encourage you to try to prove them yourself.

Comment: @Brain: Look at the subject line, please.

Comment: @user10354138 yes you are correct, I will edit my post, sorry about that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes you are correct .... I am so sorry ....I edited my question now.

Comment: You still have an error in the final line, the next to last normal symbol.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I just edited it ... thank you!

Comment: I do not know the meaning of characteristic .... this is why I need a proof without using the word characteristic.@ArturoMagidin

Comment: What you should do is **learn** what the word means in this context, because it's *important*. I posted a proof, but not because of what you wrote, which to be perfectly honest, is a rather bad position to take. It just perpetuates ignorance, instead of remedying it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $K$ is a group, then $K'$ is the subgroup of $K$ generated by all elements of the form $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, as $x,y$ range over all elements of $K$. (If your convention as $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, the argument is essentially the same.)

**Definition.** Let $H\leq G$. We say that $H$ is

1. *Normal* if and only if for every $g\in G$, $gHg^{-1}=H$. That is, for all $\phi\in\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, $\phi(H)=H$, where $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ are the inner automorphisms of $G$.
2. *Characterstic* if and only if for every $\varphi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, $\varphi(H)=H$.
3. *Fully invariant* if and only if for every $\phi\in\mathrm{End}(G)$, $\phi(H)\leq H$.

Note that fully invariant implies characteristic implies normal.

**Proposition.** Let $H\leq K\leq G$. If $K\triangleleft G$ and $H$ is characteristic in $K$, then $H\triangleleft G$.

*Proof.* Let $g\in G$. Then the map $\phi\colon K \to K$ given by  $k\longmapsto gkg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $K$, because $K$ is normal. Since $H$ is characteristic in $K$, it follows that $\phi(H)=H$. That is, for each $h\in H$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Thus, for each $g\in G$, $h\in H$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$. Thus, $H\triangleleft G$, as claimed. $\Box$

**Propostion.** Let $K$ be a group. Then $K'$ is fully invariant in $K$; in particular, it is characteristic in $K$.

*Proof.* Since $K'$ is generated by elements $[x,y]$, it suffices to show that if $\phi\in\mathrm{End}(K)$, then for all $x,y\in K$ we have $\phi([x,y])\in K'$.

Indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
\phi([x,y]) &= \phi(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)\\
&= \phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)^{-1}\phi(x)\phi(y)\\
&= [\phi(x),\phi(y)] \in K'.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $\phi(K')\leq K'$, as claimed. $\Box$

**Corollary.** For every $n\geq 0$, $G^{(n)}\triangleleft G$.

Comment: what is the meaning of fully invariant?

Comment: @Brain: I wrote down the definition. Did you not bother to read the post before asking about it?

Comment: I am very very sorry.