# why "this means that $G'' \subset Z(G')$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups, derived-subgroup

I am trying to understand the proof of the following question:

Show that if $G'/G^{''}$ and $G^{''}/G^{'''}$ are both cyclic then $G^{''} = G^{'''}.$[you may assume $G^{'''} = 1.$ Then $G/G^{''}$ acts by conjigation on the cyclic group $G^{''}.$

I have found the following solution here [If $G'/G''$ and $G''/G'''$ are cyclic then $G''=G'''$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478125/if-g-g-and-g-g-are-cyclic-then-g-g/478175#478175):

By the third isomorphism theorem, we may as well assume that $G''' = 1$.
So we are given that $G'/G''$ and $G''/G''' = G''$ are cyclic, and we want to show that $G'' = 1$, or rather that $G'$ is abelian.

We will use the fact that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, the quotient $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.

Since $G''$ is normal, we have $G = N_G(G'')$.
Then by the fact we just mentioned, $G/C_G(G'')$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$.
But $G''$ is cyclic, so $\operatorname{Aut}(G'')$ is an abelian group.
Thus $G/C_G(G'')$ is abelian, and so $G' \subset C_G(G'')$.
But this means that $G'' \subset Z(G')$.

From here the proof follows from the fact

> $$ N \subset Z(G), ~ G/N ~~ \text{cyclic} \Rightarrow G~~ \text{is abelian} ,$$

the proof of which is basically the same as the proof of the fact about $G/Z(G)$ you mentioned.

**My question is:**

I do not understand from where the statement "this means that $G'' \subset Z(G')$" in the solution, is there a theorem saying so?

Comment: You don't need a theorem, it follows immediately from (in fact it is equivalent to)  $G' \subset C_G(G'')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_G(G'')$ is the centralizer of $G''$: it means the set of all elements that commute with every element in $G''$. So $G'\subseteq C_G(G'')$ means that every element in $G'$ commutes with every element in $G''$, so $G''$ is in the center of $G'$.